# Проверка строки на наличие только указанных символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Требуется осуществить проверку, что в строке присутствуют только символы a-z, 0-9 и -.
Я понимаю, как осуществить проверку на наличие этих символов:

```
if((/[a-z0-9\-]/.test(teststring))
```

Но как исключить в проверке все прочие?
Также вопрос - корректно ли данное регулярное выражение?

Comment: `/[a-z0-9\-]/` возьмет только один символ.

Comment: `if(/[^a-z0-9-]/.test(teststring)) { /* Неверно */ } else { /* Верно */ }`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не подойдет. Там строка `2+2` не пройдет, к примеру. И только один символ.

Comment: @entithat Читайте [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1223040/182013)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, ага, действительно, не заметил. Ну как вариант. Минус то чего поставили?))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Вас `/[a-z0-9\-]/` принимает только один символ 0-9, a-z либо -. Нам же надо, чтобы проверялась вся строка. Как уже уточнили, надо добавить символы `^` (начало строки) и `$` (конец строки). Также надо указать `+`, `[a-z0-9\-]+`, что означает "один или больше" символ.

Чтобы протестировать на все другие символы можно указать так: `^(?![a-z0-9-]+$).*$`, где `(?!)` означает "вперед смотрящее нет".

```js
const tests = ['1-2', '2a*3', '4b-0', '4!+2', '!+$'];

console.log(tests.map(e => /^[a-z0-9-]+$/.test(e))); // принимает a-z, 0-9, -
console.log(tests.map(e => /^(?![a-z0-9-]+$).*$/.test(e))); // принимает все то, что не было принято выше
```

Comment: Регулярное выражение `^(?![a-z0-9-]+$).*$` здесь излишне громоздкое, блоки предварительного просмотра применяются при наличии нескольких условий, а в ТС только одно. Кроме того, по умолчанию `.` не находит символов  перевода строки (тут это, скорее всего, не проблема, но об этом стоит упомянуть). Вообще, в контексте `RegExp.test()`, `.*$` тут просто лишнее.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, но имеет право на существование?

Comment: Не стоит усложнять простые решения, или объясните, в каких случаях стоит прибегнуть именно  к такому приёму. При использовании блоков предварительного просмотра обычно много нюансов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, я не очен силен в регулярных выражениях. Ваше решение для меня было неочевидным. Так что, мне самому трудно объяснять и решать что лучше, а что нет.

Answer (score 4):

Метод `RegExp#test` проверяет строку на наличие совпадения в любом её месте, т.е. `/[a-z0-9-]/` найдёт совпадение и в `a-1`, и в `a-1~!@#$%^&*всё-тут-может-быть—()_+|`.

В данном случае необходимо просто *инвертировать* символьный класс:

```js
if (/[^a-z0-9-]/.test(teststring)) {
//    ^ - тут        
  console.log("Формат строки неверен.");
} else {
  console.log("Формат строки правилен.");
}
```

`/[^a-z0-9-]/.test(teststring)` вернёт *true*, если в строке есть символы, отличные от указанных в исключающем символьном классе (букв, цифр и дефиса), и *false*, если таких символов нет.

**Обратите внимание**

Если нет возможности "инвертировать" результат проверки на совпадение, используйте *проверку на совпадение целой строки* с помощью "якорей" `^` и `$`:

```js
if (/^[a-z0-9-]*$/.test(teststring))
if (/^[a-z0-9-]+$/.test(teststring))
```

Квантификатор `*` требует наличия 0 и более повторов шаблона, и поэтому `/^[a-z0-9-]*$/` разрешает пустую строку. Квантификатор `+` требует наличия 1 и более повторов шаблона, и поэтому `/^[a-z0-9-]+$/` *НЕ* разрешает пустую строку.

Пример кода:

```js
const strings = ['a-1', '1a', 'a-%^&', '2+2'];
const regex = /[^a-z0-9-]/;
strings.forEach( teststring => { 
    if (regex.test(teststring)) {
      console.log(`Формат строки '${teststring}' неверен.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Формат строки '${teststring}' правилен.`);
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить квантификатор и условия начала и конца строки:

```
/^[a-z0-9-]+$/
```

Тогда будут подходить только строки, состоящие из этих символов.
Если заглавные буквы тоже принимаются, добавьте флаг игнорирования регистра:

```
/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i
```

Если дефис стоит в конце, его можно не экранировать.